# Why did Jango Fett use two different jetpack models?

Tags: star-wars

In *Episode II*, Jango Fett is seen using two different jetpack models. On Kamino, he uses a [Mitrinomon Z-6](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Z-6_jetpack) (note the exhaust nozzles on the *side*):

[image: Z-6 on Kamino]

On Geonosis, he uses a [Merr-Sonn JT-12](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/JT-12_jetpack) (note the exhaust nozzles *underneath*):

[image: JT-12 on Geonosis]

Obviously, he had to switch to the JT-12 on Geonosis because the Z-6 was destroyed on Kamino during his fight with Obi-Wan. However, Wookieepedia's article on the JT-12 claims<sup>1</sup> that

> Fett continued to alternate between his JT-12 and Z-6 models, until the latter was destroyed during a battle with Obi-Wan Kenobi on Kamino.

**Why did Fett use two different jetpack models? Why not just keep multiple Z-6s or multiple JT-12s and only use one jetpack model? Is the Z-6 better in certain situations and the JT-12 better in others?**

It is tempting to assume that the Z-6 is superior because Fett's JT-12 is not equipped with a missile on Geonosis, but *The Clone Wars* shows JT-12s equipped with missiles:

[image: JT-12s with missiles from *The Clone Wars*]

---

<sup>1</sup> Wookieepedia's claim that Fett "alternated" between the jetpack models is uncited, but screenshots from [*Star Wars Bounty Hunter*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Bounty_Hunter) confirm it. If memory serves, he used the Z-6 when he was equipped with the jetpack-launched missiles, and the JT-12 when he was not. But this was likely a game mechanic or perhaps just following the portrayal in *Episode II*,  since the JT-12 was capable of carrying and launching a missile as well.

Comment: Z-6 gets destroyed. Fett goes to the store and they're out of stock of the Z-6. He gets the JT-12 instead.

Comment: @phantom42 He had both jetpacks long before the Z-6 was destroyed on Kamino. Maybe Z-6s are hard to come by (it might be the answer) but Boba managed to find one.

Comment: This is more interesting than anything else in *Episode II*.

Comment: It's far more likely he just walks into the store, grabbed the closest thing, and walked out ( without paying since he's a badass) then would just modify it to his needs if it turns out one model is inferior.

Comment: Why not? Why do people use two different cars

Comment: He's a bounty hunter. It's likely he'd just use adequate "liberated" equipment to replace the destroyed material.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that Jango Fett used a different jetpack depending on the combat situation. It appears that the Z-6 Model is larger and thus (possibly) more accurate or lethal (larger rocket may mean higher rate of burn) while the JT-12 Model is smaller and more compact, thus making it more appropriate for the close combat he was expecting to encounter on Geonosis. This would also explain why he did not revert back to the Z-6 Model after his encounter with Obi-Wan Kenobi. This is all speculation as there is not much else to go off of.